# How to get the number of files in directory in variable in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have tried following command to do this but it's not working :

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "d:/Database/BARC/" /b/a-d | find /v /c "::") do set count=%%i
```

It is showing some error like `unexpected error`. How to round this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "d:/Database/BARC/" /b/a-d ^| find /v /c "::"') do set count=%%i 
echo %count%
```